# Sequential BANGs in a bash script

Tags: bash, command-line

I'm trying to understand what the following bash script snippet is doing. 
 The sequential bangs ('!') are the main thing tripping me up, and searching online doesn't seem to really yield anything useful.

```
for file in $(find $pwd/localroot -type f ! -path '*\.git*' ! -path '*README\.md' ! -path "*?scriptname"); do
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means "not". From [the find(1) man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find):

> ```
> ! expr
> ```
>
> True if *expr* is false. This character will also usually need protection from interpretation by the shell.

There are implicit *ands* between each of the tests.

- Find files: `-type f`
- But not inside `.git` directories: `! -path '*\.git*'`
- And ignore `README.md`: `! -path '*README\.md'`
- And ignore `?scriptname`: `! -path "*?scriptname"`, where `?` is a single character.